# Distance between sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $K \subset K_1 \subset U \subset \Bbb R^2$, such that $K$ and $K_1$ are compact sets, with $K \subset \mathring {K_1}$, and $U = \mathring U \subsetneq \Bbb R ^2$.

If $w \in  \partial K_1$ such that $d(w, U^c) < \frac{d(w,K)}{2}$, show that $\frac{d(w,w')}{d(w',z)} \le \frac 1 2 \space \forall z \in K$, where $w' \in U^c$ such that $d(w,w')= d(w, U^c)$. (As usual, $U^c = \Bbb R^2 \setminus U$.)

Comment: If not, then $d\left(  w,w^{\prime}\right)  >\frac{1}{2}d\left(  w^{\prime
},z\right)  \geq\frac{1}{2}d\left(  w^{\prime},K\right)  $. Also by
assumption: $d\left(  w,w^{\prime}\right)  <\frac{1}{2}d\left(  w,K\right)  $.
Thus $d\left(  w^{\prime},K\right)  <d\left(  w,K\right)  $ for $w^{\prime}\in
U^{c},~w\in\partial K_{1}.$Just need to prove this is impossible.

Comment: note that $d(w, K) \leq d(w, z) \ \forall z \in K$ by definition